# in Gradient Boosting, why are new trees, fit to the gradient of loss function instead of residual

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I went through the explanation here ( http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/01/23/a-kaggle-master-explains-gradient-boosting/), but don't understand why the new trees in gradient boosting try to predict he gradient of loss function instead of actual residual ( y-y^). 
And is my understanding right that the first tree uses (as its prediction) a simple constant value to approximate true values , like a median for all the y.

Also, another question is how does it work for classification.

Can anyone please explain the statement made below, in detail if possible, in here [Understanding gradient boosting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/335859/understanding-gradient-boosting)

"In general, gradient boosting, when used for classification, fits trees not on the level of the gradient of predicted probabilities, but to the gradient of the predicted log-odds."

Comment: you can use mathjax for math typesetting. more information: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Matthew Drury   can you please answer this

Answer (score 3):

For (half) squared error loss the negative gradient *is* the residual. In general, a tree is fit to the gradient in order to avoid overfitting, since the loss $L(y_i,\hat{y}_i)$ can be made arbitrarily small if we constantly add to $\hat{y}_i$ the (scaled) negative gradient of $L(\cdot)$ wrt $\hat{y}_i$. The additive expansion of trees (boosting) stops when the test error has settled in.